# Coloring Individual Points of a Scatter Plot in Python3

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter

I am currently working on a project that deals with a scatter plot, made using matplotlib and numpy, 
I was wondering whether I could assign color to each point based on their (x,y) coordinates, assume that I have a function that maps (x,y) to (r,g,b). There are a lot of points (~250,000).

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib's `scatter` plot supports this via the `color` parameter, check this [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-scatter-py). You have to prepare your colors beforehand and pass it to the color. [As mentioned](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), `color` can be a sequence.

Another way, maybe slightly faster, would be to use `seaborn`'s [scatter plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/different_scatter_variables.html).